# Walking and cycling

Tags: logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

Claire walks to work at 6km/hr and Charles cycles along the same route. Normally Charles
overtakes Claire outside the public library. One day Claire leaves 20 minutes late and Charles
overtakes her outside the swimming pool, 3km before she gets to the library.
At what speed does Charles cycle?

A 9km/hr

B 12km/hr

C 15km/hr

D 18km/hr

E 24km/hr

Comment: We only have one distance. Is that enough? Do they normally arrive at the library at the same time?

Comment: Claire must be walking a bit slower today if she's only 20 minutes late ($\frac{1}{3}$ of an hour), yet she is 3km behind ($\frac{1}{2}$ of her spead).

Answer (score 1):

Given:

> Distance: 3 km
>   Time: 20 minutes
>   Velocity: ?

Pretty easy to calculate: *Velocity = Distance/Time*

So the **delta** of their speeds is: 3 km / 20 min = 9 km/h

Knowing that and the velocity of Claire we can easily find the velocity of Charles: 6 km/h + 9 km/h = **15 km/h**

So the answer is: **C**

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I just don't quite understand why the velocity found is the difference between their speeds?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why I have so much trouble doing it more easily, but very well. Let $x_0$ be Claire's initial position and $x_1$ be Charles's (both in $km$). Let $v_1$ be Charles's velocity in $km/h$. We can describe the normal process as an equation

\begin{equation}x_0 + 6t = x_1 + v_1t\end{equation}

where $t$ is how long Claire takes to meet Charles (at the public library).
Now, when she is late, we can similarly describe it as

$$x_0 + 6\tilde{t} = x_1 + v_1\left(\tilde{t}+\tfrac13\right)$$

where $\tilde{t}$ is how long Claire takes ot meet Charles (outside the swimming pool), and the $\tfrac13$ comes from the fact that Charles had already been cycling for 20 minutes, or $\tfrac13$ of an hour, before Claire began walking.

Moreover, we can relate these equations (which describe the positions at which they meet, in $km$) by

$$x_1 + v_1t - 3 = x_1 + v_1(\tilde{t} + \tfrac13)$$

Now it's a matter of juggling these equations. From the thrid equation we obtain $$v_1 = \frac{3}{t - \tilde{t} - \tfrac13}$$

The first two imply $$x_0 - x_1 = t(v_1 - 6) = \tilde{t}(v_1 - 6) + \frac{v_1}{3} $$
so that$$t - \tilde{t} = \frac{v_1}{3(v_1-6)} $$

Substituting back into the expression we previously obtained for $v_1$, simple arithmetics yield $v_1 = 18$. So Charles's velocity is $18km/h$.